# Debugging appengine in Java with breakpoints

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, maven, debugging

I'm struggling to get breakpoints to work in a Google Appengine project. I followed the guide here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/webtoolsplatform which explains how to set up a google app engine server on your local machine and run your app locally. I can do all that.

I can access my app via `http://localhost:8888` as well as `http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/explorer` etc.

Now onto my problem. None of my breakpoints stop! Even when I place a break point in every possible location the server could go to, nothing happens. This is true when I browse code normally on the regular `http://localhost:8888` site, or the /_ah/api/explorer section.

When I shut down the server, everything stops (so I know the server created by Eclipse is the one running the show) and when I am in debug-view I can manually suspend the entire app (which will also

[image: Picture of set up]

I am running the Google App Engine tutorial project from Udacity:
https://www.udacity.com/course/progress#!/c-ud859

It is a maven based project (though for this debugging, I am compiling using the Google App Engine tutorial linked at the top)

It github repo is here https://github.com/udacity/ud859
And my forked repo where I have my exact code is here:
https://bitbucket.org/esend7881/udacity-googleapp.git

I really can't tell what I am missing here.

Comment: did you ever resolve this? I've got the same issue

Answer (score 0):

This could be anything...it is working for me (using tic tac toe example: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-java

[image]

One question, is how are you invoking your API?  I don't see a "HttpMethod.GET" in yoru screen
shot.

1. Are your break points enabled, makes sure that "Skip All Breakpoints" isn't clicked":
     http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fbreakpoints%2Fref-skipall_viewaction.htm
2. I run my eclipse as "administrator" on windows to make sure it has privilege to access the director eclipse is in (Right Click on Eclipse->Run As Administrator)
3. If above fails, you can try a namespace filter (take your API out of the path) and set a break point in it.  I don't have a great example online, but you can follow the "multitenant" example on google to try it: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/multitenancy/multitenancy#Java_Setting_the_current_namespace